# Performing logical operations on the values of a column in PySpark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame with multiple columns and one of them is following. I would like to do some logical operations like **if count > 0.0** replace the value with **1.0**  else **0.0** and create another column with title **label**. How could I do it in PySpark

---

```
Count
-------
  0
  1
  2
  3
  0
  100
```

## Answer

I managed to solve this as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
cond1 = col("Count") > 0.0 
df = df.withColumn("label", when(cond1, 1.0).otherwise(0.0))
```